# Graph not displayed in jupyter notebook (ml) and 'TreeEnsemble' object has no attribute 'values' , there is no such error in vscode

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, shap

Graph not displayed in jupyter notebook and there is an issue:

> 'TreeEnsemble' object has no attribute 'values'

there is no such error in vs code

Code:

```
import shap
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

data = pd.read_csv('D:/train_for_an.csv')

X = data.drop('Survived', axis=1)
y = data['Survived']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=7, learning_rate=0.1, depth=3)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

score = model.score(X_test, y_test)
shap.initjs()
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, data = X)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV21l.png)

I was expecting to see a graph, but in Visual Studio Code the error

> 'TreeEnsemble' object has no attribute 'values'

is not present

Comment: Always provide the full error traceback. What version of shap do you have, and are you sure it's the same between vscode and jupyter?

Comment: I have 0.44.0 version shap

Comment: I have version 3.11.4 of python.